# Reordering rows in a tables following a custom order

Tags: r, formatting

I have the following block of code:

```
q1 <- VectorSource(hcsv$one)
  q1 <- q1[1:81]
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==1, "Very good")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==2, "Good")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==3, "Average")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==4, "Poor")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==5, "Very poor")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==77, "Unsure")
  q1 <-replace(q1, q1==99, "No answer")
 frequencyQ1 <- table(q1)
write.csv(frequencyQ1, "frequencyQ1.csv")
```

How can I have the output table display the rows in the custom order listed above?

Comment: Create a factor variable. See `?factor` set the levels to match your desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing the values with the labels, convert the vector into `ordered`:

```
q1 <- sample(c(1:5, 77, 99), 100, T)

q1 <- ordered(q1, labels= c("Very good", "Good", "Average",
                            "Poor", "Very poor", "Unsure", "No answer"))

table(q1)

q1
Very good      Good   Average      Poor Very poor    Unsure No answer 
       15        14        13        21         9        16        12
```